# Claymore Miner With Multi GPUs

Tags: mining, claymore, nvidia

Issue:
When I initiate "start.bat", I am noticing that the Miner only recognizes that I have (1) GPU being recognized. Although, I do have 6 of these cards all properly connected, powered on and updated with the most recent drivers.

Am I missing something here?

Software: 
**Windows 7 Ultimate x64

Claymore Eth/SIA Dual Miner V11.0**

Hardware: 
**6 NVidia GTX-1070 Cards

1 MSI Z270-A PRO Motherboard

1 4GB RAM

1 1500w Power Supply**

Config:

```
EthDcrMiner64.exe -epool us1.ethpool.org:3333 -ewal 0xc566e10De2d070F2F7aB0455eE1f8C2AAF269347 -epsw x -dpool stratum+tcp://us-east.siamining.com:7777 -dwal 5852e111dfe4c90946457f956c5822a9e5834d7b6c197ed246f42e138bf968b5293bedba3574 -mode 0 -dcoin sia
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `-eres 0` option helped me